# How do I use regular expressions and backreferences with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to remove the bracket from the date field in an Nginx access log. I tried

```
sed -E 's#\[(\d+)#\1#' access.log | head
```

But it still prints

```
172.31.20.98 - - [30/Sep/2018:20:01:01 +0000] "GET ...
```

I originally tried to change the date format, but that didn't work.

```
sed -E 's#(\d+)/(\w+)/(\d+)#\3-\2-\1#' access.log
```

Comment: `\d` and `\w` are pcre shorthand character classes and are not supported by the ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax. Instead you can use simple ranges like `[0-9]` or `[a-zA-Z]`. (You can also use POSIX character classes: `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alpha:]]`)

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to remove the `[` and `]` you can do that in two steps with each of those meta characters escaped with a backslash:

```
$ echo '172.31.20.98 - - [30/Sep/2018:20:01:01 +0000] "GET ...' | sed 's/\[//; s/\]//'
172.31.20.98 - - 30/Sep/2018:20:01:01 +0000 "GET ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using good old Perl.

```
perl -pe 's#\[(\d+)/(\w+)/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+) \+0000\]#"$3-$2-$1 $4:$5:$6"#' < access.log

172.31.20.98 - - "2018-Sep-30 20:01:01" ...
```